# ConfigurationManager return null when using to extract database connection string when add migration

Tags: c#, configuration, .net-core, entity-framework-core-2.2

I am using Entity Framework Core in my .NET Core console app. I store my connection string in the `App.config` file and use `ConfigurationManager` in context class to access the connection string.

When I want to add new migration to my project I get the following error:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> at EF_tut.Context.OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) in C:\..\Context.cs:line 12
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalAccessorExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
>
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1 factory)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.b__0()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
>
> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

This is my `App.config` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
         <add name="EfTutDb" 
              connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=EF_tut;Integrated Security=True;"/>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

and this is my context class:

```
class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EfTutDb"].ConnectionString); // Line 12.
    }
}
```

When I try get connection string using `ConfigurationManger` in the main method, I get the connection string but when I add migration, I get Null Reference error.

Comment: .Net core has a different configuration system. I don't know if ConfigurationManager works, but even if it does [I suggest you don't use it.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: i have encountered the same problem today, i'm trying to separate the Domain Classes so i need it in a separate library to connect to azure sql and using the app.config for the connectionstring. Using the ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AzureTestDbContext"].ConnectionString  returns a 'System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'.  is there anyway to use the ConfigurationManager? my temp solution was also using the hard coded connection string as well.

Answer (score 4):

The EF Core instantiates the DB context at design-times such as Add-migration or Update-Database, to gather details about the entities and map them.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#design-time-dbcontext-configuration

But the App.config of your project is not accessible using the ConfigurationManager, since the EF core design-time is another application with its own application settings.

I faced the same problem and found this solution which works for me:

App.config:

```
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Default" 
        connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=EFCoreSample;Integrated Security=SSPI"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Add a constructor to the DB context which receives a DbContextOptions and passes it to the base constructor:

```
public class EFCoreSampleDbContext : DbContext
{
    public EFCoreSampleDbContext(DbContextOptions options)
        : base(options)
    {

    }
}
```

Define a design-time DB context factory, which uses ConfigurationBuilder to retrieve the connection string from the App.config. When you run a command such as add-migration, EF Core looks for a class inside the project which implements the IDesignTimeDbContextFactory to receive an instance of the DB context, and if not found, instantiates the Db context by itself.

You can find more about the design-time DB context factory here:

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#from-a-design-time-factory[2]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#from-a-design-time-factory%5B2%5D)

You need to add Nuget packages Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration, Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions, and Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Xml for this one. Also, set the "Copy to Output Directory" property of the App.config file to "Copy always".

```
public class DesignTimeDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<EFCoreSampleDbContext>
{
    public EFCoreSampleDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var optionsBuilder =
            new DbContextOptionsBuilder<EFCoreSampleDbContext>();

        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddXmlFile("App.config")
            .Build();

        string connectionString;
        if (configuration
            .Providers
            .FirstOrDefault()
            .TryGet("connectionStrings:add:Default:connectionString",
                out connectionString))
        {

            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
            var dbContext =
                new EFCoreSampleDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
            return dbContext;
        }
        else
            throw new Exception("The design-time connection string not found!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's a bit workaround.. but this will work:

```
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)
            .AddXmlFile("App.config")
            .Build(); 

        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetValue<string>("connectionStrings:add:EfTutDb:connectionString"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not quite certain, but I think you must fix the connection string.
Try this in your class:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=YourPcName\\YourSqlServerName;Database=YourDbName;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;");
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's works when I hard coded connection string in DbContext class. The problem is when using it via ConfigurationManager.

Comment: Truth to be told, I've never used Entity Framework in console application, only in web. The difference between EF and EF-Core is that the EF-Core reads connection string from a json file called appsettings.json, not from Web.Config. I think your best bet would be to visit the official documentation and tutorial here:

https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/entity-framework-core-console-application.aspx

Best of luck :)