# Access App.config from IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<T>

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

In order to perform migrations via Entity Framework Core, I have created a design time factory, as described in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dbcontext-creation#from-a-design-time-factory). Currently, I have implemented this, which seems to work:

```
public StudentContextCreateDbContext(string[] args)
{
    string connectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=MyCatalog;Integrated Security=True;";
    var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<StudentContext>();
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
    return new StudentContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
}
```

However, I would prefer not to use a hardcoded connection string. I have tried this line instead, to get it from `App.config`:

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Local"].ConnectionString;
```

Which returns the exact same connection string, just from the `App.config` file. It works in the actual application, but when I use it from my design time factory, I get a `System.NullReferenceException`.

How can I share the same connection string between my application and my design time factory, without manually maintaining both?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ConfigurationManager return null when using to extract database connection string when add migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55659207/configurationmanager-return-null-when-using-to-extract-database-connection-strin)

Answer (score 0):

The EF Core instantiates the DB context at design-times, such as Add-migration or Update-Database, to gather details about the entities and map them. But the App.config of your project is not accessible using the ConfigurationManager, since the EF core design-time is another application with its own application settings.

Find the solution from my answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65221508/2818667